# chapter 8 rubytutorial - NoMethodError: undefined method `forget' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I am learning from rubytutorial and am having this error.
I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220402/hartl-rails-tutorial-chapter-8-46-nomethoderror) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220402/hartl-rails-tutorial-chapter-8-46-nomethoderror) but still does not work.
I attached session_helper.rb and user.rb here.
could someone show me where I miss?

```
1) Error:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout:
NoMethodError: undefined method `forget' for nil:NilClass
    app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:25:in `forget'
    app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:32:in `log_out'
    app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:19:in `destroy'
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:33:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'

22 runs, 50 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

session_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper
    # Logs in the given user.
    def log_in(user)
        session[:user_id] = user.id
    end

    def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
      log_in user
      @current_user = user
      end
    end
    end

    def logged_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end

    # Forgets a persistent session.
    def forget(user)
      user.forget
      cookies.delete(:user_id)
      cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    end

    # Logs out the current user.
    def log_out
      forget(current_user)
      session.delete(:user_id)
      @current_user = nil
    end  

    # Remembers a user in a persistent session.
    def remember(user)
      user.remember
      cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
      cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    end
  end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :remember_token
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
    return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end

  # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message indicates that you have an:

> undefined method forget' for nil:NilClass

This means that you attempted to call a method (`forget`) on an object that did not have that method (`nil`). Looking at the part of your code where the error is coming from...

```
def forget(user)
      user.forget
```

...you can see that you are calling forget on the variable `user`. This is being called from the log_out method:

```
def log_out
  forget(current_user)
```

So, you are passing `current_user` to the `forget` method, and then calling `forget` on it. Only, it is not an instance of the User class (like you expected), which does have a `forget` method, but rather is `nil`. `nil` does not have a forget method.

This is probably nil because you are not authenticated and there is no `current_user`. One way to remedy this would be to check if the current user actually exists before forgetting it, like this:

```
def log_out
  current_user && forget(current_user)
```

A more sophisticated way to handle this issue would be with the [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), where `current_user` would return an instance of User with minimal authorizations, instead of nil.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but I still do not know what to do. :)
do you mean that the database is empty?

Comment: @Codelearner777  No I mean that there is not a signed in (or authenticated) user. "Nil" means "nothing". Change your code like in teh example above, and see what happens.

Comment: I tried it and it works! thank you.
I still dont get it though and am reading chapter 8 again.
I really appriciate your help.

Comment: @Codelearner777 You're very welcome. Basically, the log out method was expecting someone to be logged in before they hit it. Now we made it so you don't have to be logged in, and you can still log out...

Answer (score 1):

Look at your log, you are trying to call `.forget` on `nil` object:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `forget' for nil:NilClass
```

That means you passed `nil` to `SessionsHelper#forget`, so your `current_user` is `nil`.

Are you trying to logout an user currently not logged-in? If not, there should be something wrong with method `current_user` because it return `nil` while user already logged-in.

Comment: lol, I noticed we post the answer at the same time but I forgot to jinx you :))

Comment: thanks for your answer. but I still do not know what to do. :)

Answer (score 1):

Soooo, I realize this is like 2 years later... but I had the same issue here as OP...

my solution was (as explained in the tutorial) to change the `destroy` method in the `SessionsController` from:

```
def destroy
   log_out
   redirect_to root_url
 end
```

to:

```
def destroy
   log_out if logged_in?
   redirect_to root_url
 end
```

In case anyone else is as late to the rails game as I am... hope this helps